# QueryDsl in JSONB column postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, querydsl

I have an object which has jsonb column. Is there any way to query into this jsonb column using querydsl?

Here is an example of my objects:

```
public class Person {
  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private PersonDocument personDocument;

}


public class PersonDocument {
  private int documentType;
  private List<DocumentDetail> documentDetails;
}

public class DocumentDetail {
  private String country;
  private String documentId;
  private LocalDate expiryDate
}
```

I would like to search person by documentId, so I need to get to documentId column

Comment: You'll need to implement and register a custom type: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s03.html

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling do you have some example since I dont see anything with jsonb column in the referenced link

Comment: No there aren't any examples for JSONB unfortunately, QueryDSL doesn't support it out of the box as it is PostgreSQL specific. You'd have to cook your own.

Answer (score 1):

QueryDSL doesn't have any support for queries on PostgreSQL jsonb column. I have one solution that works for Query on the PostgreSQL field using QueryDSL.
solution steps:

1. Create a database view using the table where jsonb column. The view uses to convert your jsonb to the table normal table structure. like table A(j jsonb) now you want the field "xyz" from "j" jsonb column from A table. you can apply the following query:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_b as select a.id as a_id,a->> "xyz" as xyz from A a`

now, view table structure like `view_b(a_id,xyz)`

2. Now you create a domain object which represents this view.

   `@Table(name="view_b") public class ViewB{...}`
3. now you can query using query DSL. like qViewB.xyz.eq("value")